# WaitForMultipleObjects starving out

Tags: winapi

When I call WaitForMultipleObjects on a set of objects and another thread is waiting for a single object of that set with WaitForSingleObject, this thread is preferred and the thread calling WaitForMultipleObjects never gets CPU-time.

Look at this source:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unordered_map>

HANDLE        hEvt,
              hSema;
bool volatile fReleased;

DWORD WINAPI LockAndReleaseThread( LPVOID lpvThreadParam );

int main()
{
    int const NTHREADS = 10;
    HANDLE    ahWait[2];

    ahWait[0] = ::hEvt  = CreateEvent( NULL, FALSE, TRUE, NULL );
    ahWait[1] = ::hSema = CreateSemaphore( NULL, 0, 1, NULL );
    fReleased = false;

    for( int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++ )
        CreateThread( NULL, 0, LockAndReleaseThread, NULL, 0, NULL );

    for( ; ; )
        WaitForMultipleObjects( 2, ahWait, TRUE, INFINITE ),
        std::printf( "main thread is holding lock and received signal\n" ),
        ::fReleased = false,
        SetEvent( ::hEvt );

    return 0;
}

char GetID();

DWORD WINAPI LockAndReleaseThread( LPVOID lpvThreadParam )
{
    for( ; ; )
    {
        WaitForSingleObject( ::hEvt, INFINITE );
        std::printf( "spawned thread with id %c is holding lock\n", (char)GetID() );

        if( !::fReleased )
            ReleaseSemaphore( ::hSema, 1, NULL ),
            ::fReleased = true;

        Sleep( 1000 );
        SetEvent( ::hEvt );
    }

    return 0;
}

char GetID()
{
    static std::unordered_map<DWORD, char> mapTIDsToIDs;
    static char                            nextId = 'A';
    DWORD                                  dwThreadId;

    if( mapTIDsToIDs.find( dwThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId() ) == mapTIDsToIDs.end() )
        return mapTIDsToIDs[dwThreadId] = nextId++;
    else
        return mapTIDsToIDs[dwThreadId];
}
```

In this code, the main thread never gets CPU-time if NTHREADS is >= 2.
I don't expect WaitForSingleObject or WaitForMultipleObjects to be completely fair, but this looks to me like a conceptual flaw.

If I replace

```
WaitForMultipleObjects( 2, ahWait, TRUE, INFINITE ),
```

with

```
WaitForSingleObject( ::hSema, INFINITE ),
WaitForSingleObject( ::hEvt, INFINITE ),
```

the main-thread gets CPU-time.

[EDIT1]

The bug hasn't been fixed even with Windows 10.
And doing WaitForMultipleObjects instead of WaitForSingleObject doesn't change the situation.
And the spawned threads get CPU-time in a round-robin-fashion and it doesn't matter if there is a Sleep or not and if I'm doing WaitforSingleObject or WaitForMultipleObjects.

The tip with using a critical section here doesn't help me.

I've developed a condition-variable where this constellation can happen if multiple threads are locking the condvar and one is waiting for the condvar to be singalled:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <exception>
#include <intrin.h>

#if !defined(NDEBUG)
    #define ONDEBUG(expr) (expr)
#else
    #define ONDEBUG(expr) ((void)0)
#endif

inline
DWORD FastGetCurrentThreadId()
{
#if defined(_M_IX86)
    return __readfsdword( 0x24 );
#elif defined(_M_AMD64)
    return *(DWORD *)(__readgsqword( 0x30 ) + 0x48);
#endif
}

class Exception : public std::exception
{
};

class ResourceException : public Exception
{
};

template <typename TYPE>
inline
TYPE AutoThrowResourceException( TYPE t )
{
    if( !t )
        throw ResourceException();

    return t;
}

class XHANDLE
{
public:
         XHANDLE( HANDLE h = NULL );
         ~XHANDLE();
    void CloseHandle();

public:
    HANDLE h;
};

inline
XHANDLE::XHANDLE( HANDLE h )
{
    this->h = h;
}

inline
XHANDLE::~XHANDLE()
{
    BOOL fClosed;

    if( h && h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        fClosed = ::CloseHandle( h ),
        assert(fClosed);
}

inline
void XHANDLE::CloseHandle()
{
    ::CloseHandle( h );
    h = NULL;
}


class CondVar
{
public:
         CondVar();
         ~CondVar();
    void Enter();
    void Wait();
    void Release();
    void ReleaseAll();
    void Leave();

private:
    LONGLONG volatile m_llOwnersAndWaiters;
    DWORD    volatile m_dwRecursionCount;
    DWORD    volatile m_dwOwningThreadId;
    XHANDLE           m_xhEvtEnter,
                      m_xhSemRelease;

private:
    static
    DWORD Owners( LONGLONG llOwnersAndWaiters )
    {
        return (DWORD)llOwnersAndWaiters;
    }

    static
    DWORD Waiters( LONGLONG llOwnersAndWaiters )
    {
        return (DWORD)((DWORDLONG)llOwnersAndWaiters >> 32);
    }
};

CondVar::CondVar() :
    m_xhEvtEnter(   AutoThrowResourceException( ::CreateEvent( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL ) ) ),
    m_xhSemRelease( AutoThrowResourceException( ::CreateSemaphore( NULL, 0, 0x7FFFFFFF, NULL ) ) )
{
    m_llOwnersAndWaiters = 0;
    m_dwRecursionCount   = 0;
    m_dwOwningThreadId   = 0;
}

CondVar::~CondVar()
{
}

void CondVar::Enter()
{
    if( m_dwOwningThreadId == FastGetCurrentThreadId() )
    {
        m_dwRecursionCount++;
        return;
    }

    LONGLONG llOwnersAndWaiters = ::InterlockedIncrement64( &m_llOwnersAndWaiters  );

    assert(Owners( llOwnersAndWaiters ) > Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters ));

    if( (Owners( llOwnersAndWaiters ) - Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters )) > 1 )
        for( ; ::WaitForSingleObject( m_xhEvtEnter.h, INFINITE ) != WAIT_OBJECT_0; assert(false) );

    ONDEBUG(llOwnersAndWaiters = m_llOwnersAndWaiters);
    assert(Owners( llOwnersAndWaiters ) > Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters ) && m_dwOwningThreadId == 0);

    m_dwOwningThreadId = FastGetCurrentThreadId();
}

void CondVar::Wait()
{
    LONGLONG llOwnersAndWaiters;
    DWORD    dwSavedRecusionCount;

    ONDEBUG(llOwnersAndWaiters = m_llOwnersAndWaiters);
    assert(Owners( llOwnersAndWaiters ) > Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters ) && m_dwOwningThreadId == FastGetCurrentThreadId());

    m_dwOwningThreadId   = 0;
    dwSavedRecusionCount = m_dwRecursionCount;
    m_dwRecursionCount   = 0;
    llOwnersAndWaiters   = ::InterlockedAdd64( &m_llOwnersAndWaiters, 0x100000000 );

    if( Owners( llOwnersAndWaiters ) > Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters ) )
        for( ; !::SetEvent( m_xhEvtEnter.h ); assert(false) );

    HANDLE ahWait[2] = { m_xhEvtEnter.h, m_xhSemRelease.h };

    for( ; ::WaitForMultipleObjects( 2, ahWait, TRUE, INFINITE ) != WAIT_OBJECT_0; assert(false) );

    ONDEBUG(llOwnersAndWaiters = m_llOwnersAndWaiters);
    assert(Owners( llOwnersAndWaiters ) > Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters ) && m_dwOwningThreadId == 0);

    m_dwOwningThreadId = FastGetCurrentThreadId();
    m_dwRecursionCount = dwSavedRecusionCount;
}

void CondVar::Release()
{
    LONGLONG llOwnersAndWaiters,
             llOwnersAndWaitersPrevOrChanged;

    for( llOwnersAndWaiters = m_llOwnersAndWaiters; Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters ); llOwnersAndWaiters = llOwnersAndWaitersPrevOrChanged )
    {
        assert(Owners( llOwnersAndWaiters ) > Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters ) && m_dwOwningThreadId == FastGetCurrentThreadId());

        if( (llOwnersAndWaitersPrevOrChanged = ::InterlockedCompareExchange64( &m_llOwnersAndWaiters, llOwnersAndWaiters - 0x100000000, llOwnersAndWaiters )) == llOwnersAndWaiters )
        {
            for (; !::ReleaseSemaphore( m_xhSemRelease.h, 1, NULL ); assert( false ));
            break;
        }
    }
}

void CondVar::ReleaseAll()
{
    LONGLONG llOwnersAndWaiters,
             llOwnersAndWaitersPrevOrChanged;

    for( llOwnersAndWaiters = m_llOwnersAndWaiters; Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters ); llOwnersAndWaiters = llOwnersAndWaitersPrevOrChanged )
    {
        assert(Owners( llOwnersAndWaiters ) > Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters ) && m_dwOwningThreadId == FastGetCurrentThreadId());

        if( (llOwnersAndWaitersPrevOrChanged = ::InterlockedCompareExchange64( &m_llOwnersAndWaiters, llOwnersAndWaiters & 0x0FFFFFFFF, llOwnersAndWaiters )) == llOwnersAndWaiters )
        {
            for (; !::ReleaseSemaphore( m_xhSemRelease.h, (LONG)Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters ), NULL ); assert( false ));
            break;
        }
    }
}

void CondVar::Leave()
{
    LONGLONG llOwnersAndWaiters;
    LONG     lRecursionCount;

    ONDEBUG(llOwnersAndWaiters = m_llOwnersAndWaiters);
    assert(Owners( llOwnersAndWaiters ) > Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters ) && m_dwOwningThreadId == FastGetCurrentThreadId());

    if( (lRecursionCount = m_dwRecursionCount) != 0 )
    {
        m_dwRecursionCount = lRecursionCount - 1;
        return;
    }

    m_dwOwningThreadId = 0;

    llOwnersAndWaiters = ::InterlockedDecrement64( &m_llOwnersAndWaiters );

    if( Owners( llOwnersAndWaiters ) > Waiters( llOwnersAndWaiters ) )
        for( ; !::SetEvent( m_xhEvtEnter.h ); assert(false) );
}

/* ---------------------------- unit-test ---------------------------- */

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <map>

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc( LPVOID lpvThreadParam );

using namespace std;

struct ThreadResult
{
    DWORD dwThreadId;
    DWORD dwCounter;
};

CondVar             cv;
deque<ThreadResult> dqtr;
bool volatile       fStop = false;

int main()
{
    int const              NTHREADS = 16;
    HANDLE                 ahThreads[NTHREADS];
    int                    i;
    std::map<DWORD, DWORD> mTRs;

    for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++ )
        ahThreads[i] = CreateThread( NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL );

    for( i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )
    {
        ThreadResult tr;

        ::cv.Enter();

        if( ::dqtr.empty() )
            ::cv.Wait();

        tr = ::dqtr.front();
        ::dqtr.pop_front();
        ::cv.Leave();

        printf( "Thread: %08X - Number: %d\n", (unsigned)tr.dwThreadId, (unsigned)tr.dwCounter );

        if( mTRs.find( tr.dwThreadId ) == mTRs.end() )
            mTRs[tr.dwThreadId] = tr.dwCounter;
        else
            assert((mTRs[tr.dwThreadId] + 1) == tr.dwCounter),
            mTRs[tr.dwThreadId] = tr.dwCounter;
    }

    for( ::fStop = true, i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++ )
        WaitForSingleObject( ahThreads[i], INFINITE );

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc( LPVOID lpvThreadParam )
{
    ThreadResult tr;

    tr.dwThreadId = FastGetCurrentThreadId();
    tr.dwCounter  = 0;

    for( ; !::fStop; tr.dwCounter++ )
    {
        ::cv.Enter();
        ::dqtr.push_back( tr );
        ::cv.Release();
        Sleep( 100 );
        ::cv.Leave();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem, and it is bizarre.

For what it's worth, I found that I could work around it by using WaitForMultipleObjects() exclusively, and including a per-thread dummy object, i.e.,

```
DWORD WINAPI LockAndReleaseThread( LPVOID lpvThreadParam )
{
    HANDLE ahWait[2];
    ahWait[0] = ::hEvt;
    ahWait[1] = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, TRUE, NULL);
    for( ; ; )
    {
        WaitForMultipleObjects(2, ahWait, TRUE, INFINITE );
        std::printf( "spawned thread with id %c is holding lock\n", (char)GetID() );

        if( !::fReleased )
            ReleaseSemaphore( ::hSema, 1, NULL ),
            ::fReleased = true;

        Sleep( 1000 );
        SetEvent( ::hEvt );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This does *not* seem to work if the child threads share a single dummy object, unless the parent thread is also waiting on that object.  So while it seems to work in this case, it is likely to be a fragile approach.

Personally at this point I'd be looking for another solution, but in your scenario I wouldn't really know where to start.  (Off the top of my head, I'm thinking a linked list of threads and perhaps some lock-free queues.)  On the other hand, since you're reading the thread ID directly from the undocumented process environment block, reliability and forwards compatibility clearly isn't a *major* issue for you, so perhaps this workaround will be sufficient. :-)

You should also note that Windows does have its own implementation of condition variables.  I'm not sure why you're rolling your own here.

Comment: @BonitaMontero, gah, yes, you're quite right.  The code I was experimenting with wasn't doing quite what I thought it was.  When I went back to your code and made just the minimal changes I'd suggested, it stopped working.  I'm *reasonably* confident that the code changes shown in my latest edit do actually work, I was more careful this time.